Can synctex be modified to not return the page number?
Consider the following document
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\par a1
\par a2
\par a3
\par a4
\par a5
\par a6
\par a7
\par a8
\par a9
\par a10
\par a11
\par a12
\par a13
\par a14
\par a15
\par a16
\par a17
\par a18
\par a19
\par a20
\par a21
\par a22
\par a23
\par a24
\par a25
\par a26
\par a27
\par a28
\par a29
\par a30
\par a31
\par a32
\par a33
\par a34
\par a35
\par a36
\par a37
\par a38
\par a39
\par a40
\par a41
\par a42
\par a43
\par a44
\par a45
\par a46
\par a47
\par a48
\par a49
\par a50
\par a51
\par a52
\par a53
\par a54
\par a55
\par a56
\par a57
\par a58
\par a59
\par a60
\par a61
\par a62
\par a63
\par a64
\par a65
\par a66
\par a67
\par a68
\par a69
\par a70
\par a71
\par a72
\par a73
\par a74
\par a75
\par a76
\par a77
\par a78
\par a79
\par a80
\par a81
\par a82
\par a83
\par a84
\par a85
\par a86
\par a87
\par a88
\par a89
\par a90
\par a91
\par a92
\par a93
\par a94
\par a95
\par a96
\par a97
\par a98
\par a99
\par a100
\par a101
\end{document}

When I compile it with pdflatex, then run synctex on source code line 51, it returns:
$ synctex view -i 51:-1:a.tex -o a.pdf
This is SyncTeX command line utility, version 1.5
SyncTeX result begin
Output:a.pdf
Page:1
x:308.114594
y:702.635132
h:133.768356
v:702.635132
W:343.711060
H:6.420366
before:
offset:-1
middle:
after:
Output:a.pdf
Page:1
x:133.768356
y:99.895378
h:133.768356
v:99.895378
W:343.711060
H:0.000000
before:
offset:-1
middle:
after:
Output:a.pdf
Page:1
x:133.768356
y:702.635132
h:133.768356
v:702.635132
W:343.711060
H:6.420366
before:
offset:-1
middle:
after:
Output:a.pdf
Page:2
x:163.656326
y:146.719788
h:133.768356
v:146.719788
W:343.711060
H:6.420366
before:
offset:-1
middle:
after:
SyncTeX result end

The first 3 entries are just the page number of the first page. The last one is what I actually want to see.
Is there a way to disable the page number from being included from the output?
